# Finding Avg of all 2-Digit in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the avg of list but only when n >= 10 (two digit numbers, my original list is limited to 100).

Here's what I have right now:

```
# Calculate average of all two-digit numbers (10-99)
grade_list = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
def calcAvg(grade_list):
    while n > 10:
        total = sum(grade_list)
        n = total % len(grade_list)
        print_list = n
    return print_list
```

I get that I have to find the total sum of the list when n > 10 and then dividing by the length (only > 10, my original list has single digit elements, so I'd like to avoid them).

But when I run it, I get an error saying: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

Any help on how to structure this function to achieve the end results (sum/total of only 2-digit elements = avg)

Thanks!

Comment: You need a for loop here, not a while, as you are summing all the values that are greater than 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def calcAvg(grade_list):
    my_list = []
    total, count = 0,0
    for n in grade_list:
        if 10 <= n <= 99:
            total += n
    if not total:
        return None
    

    return total/count
```

Comment: `total` is an `int` value. Shouldn't it be `len(my_list)`?

Comment: `len(int)` raises an exception. Also, edge case - if all the values are <=10, this would raise an exception.

Comment: I'm getting an error: object of type 'int' has no len() **Edit** I just replaced the len(total) with len(my_list). And replaced the total = 0 for loop with totalsum = sum(my_list). Thanks!

Comment: >  total = 0
    for n in my_list:
        total += n
For the above code we can also simplify this to sum(my_list) and store in some variable let's say (s)
and then avg = s/len(my_list).

Answer (score 3):

I'd either collect the good grades and use `sum`/`len`, or use the `mean` function:

```
>>> grade_list = [1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> good = [g for g in grade_list if g > 10]
>>> sum(good) / len(good)
13.0

>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.mean(g for g in grade_list if g > 10)
13.0
```

Comment: `grade_list = [1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 120, 122, 320]` what about this?

Comment: @AerofoilKite He said the list already is limited to 100, so that should not happen.

Comment: Careful, in the question description there is a condition `n >= 10`

Comment: @dm295 I know. And there's also `n > 10`. Obviously he needs to make up his mind, and I don't care since it's trivial to adapt if necessary.

Comment: @StefanPochmann there should be the termination condition as the question says the original list is limited to 100. so if 100 is in the list it would take it and the answer will be wrong
**Suppose:**
`grade_list = [1, 20, 30, 100]
Your Output: 150
Expected Output: 50`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean way of doing it:

```
def calc_avg(lst):
    filtered_lst = filter(lambda x: 10 < x < 100, lst)
    return sum(filtered_lst) / len(filtered_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this fairly simply with a list comprehension

```
>>> grades = [1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 120, 122, 320]
>>> lst = [v for v in grades if 10 <= v < 100]
>>> sum(lst)/len(lst)
12
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should use a for loop instead of a while loop. Instead of having two for loops and making a new list, you could just account for the sum inside the first for loop. I demonstrate this below.

```
def calcAvg(grade_list):
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    for n in grade_list:
        if 10 <= n <= 99:
            sum = sum + n
            count = count + 1
    return sum/count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should manually go over the code step by step and try to understand what is wrong.  Meanwhile this may give you some hints

```
# Calculate average of all two-digit numbers (10-99)
def calcAvg(alist):
    count=total=0
    for i in alist:
        if 9 < i < 100:
            total += i
            count += 1
    return total/count
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Python 3.4` there is a [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module.

So you just need to filter out numbers in range <10,100), for example with a list comprehension, and then pass this filtered list to the `mean` function. Simple as that.

```
from statistics import mean

numbers = [1, 20, 30, 50]
mean([n for n in numbers if n >= 10 and n < 100])
>>> 33.333333333333336
```